# Omnet++ link connection

Tags: omnet++

I am a beginner in OMNeT++
I have created 2 nodes in NED and I wanted to connect each other
but it is giving me error:

> syntax error unexpected Connections expecting $end

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried already and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Check the [tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/part1.html) carefully, if you specify more precisely what is your problem I can help you.

Every network has a `.ned` file. This file is called topology file and describes the network's node and links between the network nodes.  If I am not mistaken if you add this code to the  file you should be able to connect the nodes using the IDE.

```
simple Txc1
{
    gates:
        input in;
        output out;
}
```

If you don't specify in the `.ned` you won't be able to connect one node to the other because your node won't have a input or output (it will be basically a useless node, in my opinion).